# SSRS report - Calculate a new field based on the value of a different field

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I am relatively new to this and would appreciate some help.

What I am trying to do is take the current value of a field and multiply it by some factor based on the value of a different field.

For example, if I have one column (Column A) that has three different values (Z, X, and Y) and another column (Column B) with a variety of numbers, I want to calculate a third field (Column C) based on these two associated values.   
 So if the value of column A is equal to 'Z' the value in Column C would be equal to Column B multiplied by 2. 
 If the value in column A is equal to 'X' the value in Column C would be equal to the value in Column B multiplied by 1.5.  
 Finally, if the value in column A is equal to 'Y' then the value in Column C would just be equal to the value in Column B.

[Example of Question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YM0lm.png)

Is there a way of doing this just as a calculated field?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the expression of the column to something like

```
= Fields!ColumnB.Value * 
SWITCH(
        Fields!ColumnA.Value = "X", 1.5,
        Fields!ColumnA.Value = "Y", 1,
        Fields!ColumnA.Value = "Z", 2,
        True, 0
)
```

The True line acts like an ELSE so anything that does not match X, Y or Z will get multiplied by 0 (resulting in zero)